# In Oracle want to convert Image BLOB data into BMP BLOB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in which I am storing all files with their clob and blob information in different columns.
In this table, I have stored JPEG images also as binary data in BLOB column.
For Report printing on middle tier I have used Rave Report which prints BMP image BLOB data.

I am storing FILE_FORMAT (jpeg, txt, docx, bmp) in this column.
I want to convert JPEG BLOB data which is stored in FILE_DATA column into BMP BLOB data using any sql script.

```
Table Name : FILES_INFORMATION
Columns : FILE_NAME, FILE_TYPE, FILE_DATA (BLOB), FILE_FORMAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Oracle Multimedia Image Processing".

There's functionality you need.

More info here: [Oracle Multimedia Image Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10776/ap_imgproc.htm#AIVUG50000)